# Controls created on one thread cannot be parented to a control on a different thread although invoking

Tags: c#

I tried all the solution from the existing threads in this forum but having no luck at all. This is my problem i am showing a from from a thread and getting this error(subject).

> System argumentexception: controls created on one thread cannot be parented to a control on a different thread

See my code below:

```
Loan.Releasing RL = new Loan.Releasing();
GlobalForm.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
{
    RL.Text = Functions.GetCustomerName(txtcustomer.Text);
    RL.ShowDialog();
});
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: move `Loan.Releasing RL = new Loan.Releasing();` inside the delegate.

Comment: "System argumentexception: controls created on one thread cannot be parented to a control on a different thread" when executing the code that i provide above it shows that error.

Comment: @nitin okay ill try and get back thanks :)

Comment: @nitin hi it works perfectly :) thank :D

Comment: @JeromeHolasca posted the same as answer so that others can be benefitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `Loan.Releasing RL = new Loan.Releasing();` inside the delegate.

The form should be created on the thread where parent will be set for it. Your delegate will be called on the primary thread, hence instantiation of form should be within the delegate